RequestSizeLimitAttribute cause HttpRequestException
I created a simple ASP.NET Core application (I tried .NET 6 and .NET 8) with a single upload API with a RequestSizeLimitAttribute.
[HttpPost(Name = "Upload")]
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000)]
public IActionResult Upload()
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Form.Files.Count != 1)
        {
            return new BadRequestResult();
        }

        return new OkResult();
    }
    catch (BadHttpRequestException ex)
    {
        if (ex.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status413PayloadTooLarge)
            return new StatusCodeResult(413);

        return new StatusCodeResult(500);
    }
}

Then I created an application to call that Upload API method:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
using var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes("[File Path Here]");
using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileContent);

multiForm.Add(new StreamContent(ms), "file", "test.data");
var res = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7125/Upload", multiForm);

When I use a file size of 250 kb, everything works fine and the filter works:
StatusCode: 413, ReasonPhrase: 'Payload Too Large', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
    Connection: close
    Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 14:32:03 GMT
    Server: Kestrel
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}, Trailing Headers:
{
}

But when I use a larger file (like 15 mb), I get this response:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
HResult=0x80131620
Message=Error while copying content to a stream.
Source=System.Net.Http
StackTrace:
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<g__WaitAsync|56_0>d.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent.d__24.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<g__WaitAsync|56_0>d.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__61.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__57.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__57.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__89.MoveNext()
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.d__4.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext()
at Program.<$>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\pcroc\source\repos\UploadFileTester\UploadFileTester\Program.cs:line 8
Inner Exception 1:
IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connessione in corso interrotta forzatamente dall'host remoto..
Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: Connessione in corso interrotta forzatamente dall'host remoto.

Where is the my mistake?
Thank you!

I got this error (but for files of all sizes) when I was not using TLS 1.2 or higher. Can you double check you are using that protocol? 15MB should be small enough that any server configuration wouldn't get in the error, but are you sure you are not setting filesize restrictions anywhere else in Startup/program.cs, or somewhere else?

I tried to force TLS 1.2 but it doesn't work. Program.cs is the one generated by Visual Studio. I don't have Startup.cs.

I am going to guess it is a TLS issue then. Can you share how it doesn't work and what you have tried? That might be the crux of your issue.

I added this line before HttpClient creation: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

I was able to reproduce your issue on my machine. So the problem is that by default Kestrel has a request body size limit which is around 28mb. You could update it up the max you want to -
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
});

